# Determine the first time a UIViewController appears

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, viewwillappear

Before [resorting to custom flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436307/how-can-i-determine-if-a-view-has-been-loaded-for-the-first-time) I wanted to check this with you people.

Is there a built-in way to determine in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewWillDisappear:` whether the UIViewController is 'newly pushed' onto a UINavigationController's stack, or whether the navigation controller has popped another view off, revealing this one? I want to execute some one-off code the first time the view appears. Because the `self.bounds` property needs to be set, the `viewDidLoad:` method is not the right place.

I was hoping to get some results with what I'm using to [determine something similar on `viewWillDisappear:`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991736/get-notified-when-a-view-controller-is-about-to-be-popped-in-ios4), but on the first `viewWillAppear:` the index is already set to 1:

```
[self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]
```

So this is a useless snippet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I handle this is as follows... Have a flag which is initially set to false, when you push a child view controller onto your navigation controller set this flag to true, no on the viewDidAppear if the flag is false then it is the initial load if true then it is being returned to from a child controller popping off the navigation stack.

Comment: Yes, that's the scenario I was hoping to prevent. I'll wait a little while longer to see if anyone else comes with a more concise solution. Otherwise this is it. Thx.

Answer (score -1):

There is no built in way to check it. This is the [detail discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153487/how-to-determine-load-application-on-iphone-at-first-time)about your query.

Comment: Actually, the question you're referring to deals with an entirely different topic.